# How to reduce gap between 2 tables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using Javascript for my ascx control. I have 2 tables, one below the other. My code written is like

```
    </tr> 
 </table>
<table style="border-spacing: 15px;">
```

But when i execute, it shows almost 2 inch space between them. Can some help me out?

Thank you!!

Comment: paste some code, I mean whole table. it can be coused by css style of upper table too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information to deduce what is causing the gap.  However, I would recommend the free [Web Developer addon for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/), which will allow you to identify all the elements on the page, and work out which element is filling that gap.

Comment: Fire Bug found to be good. I managed to clear this issue. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using the cellspacing and cellpadding attributes on table can resolve this.  Try setting these to 1, or 0 to see what the tables look like without the extra spacing/padding.

```
<table cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'>...
```

Answer (score 0):

There's most probably a CSS style somewhere in your HTML code which sets the margin before or after the tables.

Check the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
<title>Testing tables</title>
    <style>
      #t1, #t2 {
        margin: 10px;
        border-collapse: collapse; 
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
<table id="t1">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>One</th><th>Two</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="t2">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Three</th><th>Four</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Data 3</td><td>Data 4</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

After you view this code in your browser, try to replace the line `margin: 10px;` with `margin: 0` and see what's changed on the webpage.

You can use the right tools (Firefox / Chrome / Opera) to inspect which part of your code is playing tricks with you.